# How can I toggle show/hide state of pushpin's infoboxes in Bing Maps, Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, toggle, bing-maps, pushpin, infobox

It's a simple app. It show dynamic multiple pushpins based on data binding.

When user tap pushpin, the info box will show above as show in the picture.

[image]

When user tap the pushpin again. The infobox will collapsed.

And if user tap any area in the map which is not pushpin. All pushpins's infoboxes will collapsed.

The other thing is; when infobox is tapped, it will navigate into the detail page of that location.

This is my resource section.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="currentPushPin" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
           Width="58"
           Height="76"
           Margin="0">
            <Image Source="images/currentPin.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="normalPushPin" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path Data="M0,0 L0,1 L1,0"
                        Fill="Black" Stretch="Fill" Margin="15,0" Height="12"
                                Width="18" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                Path=Content.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <Image Source="images/Pin.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LogoTemplate">
        <my:Pushpin Background="#FFB6DE2E" Location="{Binding location}" Tap="Pushpin_Tap">
            <my:Pushpin.Content>
                <Border Background="Black" Width="130" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="border"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </my:Pushpin.Content>
        </my:Pushpin>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

This is my Map and MapItemControl.

```
<my:Map ZoomLevel="10"  Margin="0,-21,0,0" Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="AsbJ8nhHrawCJNpgYLyPRSunojuLOKcZtMj_ZUEgEGW5dSsczqrQHDZwbi0i2bFY" Tap="map_Tap">
            <my:Pushpin Name="currentPin" Template="{StaticResource currentPushPin}" Margin="0,-22,0,0">
            </my:Pushpin>
            <my:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogoTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpinCollection}" >
            </my:MapItemsControl>
        </my:Map>
```

The question is what code I should write in these event handlers?
Another question is how can I make infoboxes navigate to other page if it is tapped.

```
//Event Handler for pushpins
    private void Pushpin_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //What I should write here?
    }


    private void map_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //What I should write here?
    }
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this ia rather late, but to save some pain for people who have similar issues - 
Take a look at http://igrali.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/

It may give you some guidance on how to proceed.